# dojo1.7 tabs show up as normal divs

Tags: tabs, dojo

I'm trying to implement a tab control using dojo in an already existing application. Here's some of what I've done:

```
<head> 
.....
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo/dojo/dojo.js')}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
</script>
....
</head>
<body>
....
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.TabContainer" style="width: 400px; height: 100px;" tabStrip="true">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="title1" selected="true">
 ...content...
</div>
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="title2">
...content...
</div>
</div>
....
</body>
```

The js loads properly (firebug displays no errors).

When I browse to the page I see all the content divs drawn as though no formatting has taken place at all and they are just regular divs.

My first guess was that there's a css file I was meant to include. All the examples I found that work link to a hugely complex css file that does a whole lot of stuff that is inappropriate for my application. I cant find any explanations about any css that should be included so i suspect this guess is wrong.

Can anyone point out my error, or point me in the direction of a concise and up to date example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the widgets been created?  Running `dijit.registry` in the console of the browser will show you the widgets that have been created.

If they haven't been created, you need to configure dojo to parse the html.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dojo/dojo.js"
  data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
```

Dojo uses themes to give a look and feel to the widgets.  To accomplish this, you should add the following css:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/dijit.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
```

and add the claro class to the body node:

```
<body class="claro"/>
```

Comment: @Sheena, was it the parsing, css or both that was the problem?